# Is React onClick more like a JavaScript addEventListener than like a standard JavaScript onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

In React is it better to think of onClick as setting an eventListener rather than as a standard JavaScript onclick attribute?

For example, consider these two code snippets, the first in standard JavaScript, the second in React:

```html
<button onclick="activateLasers()">
  Activate Lasers
</button>

<button onClick={activateLasers}>
  Activate Lasers
</button>
```

In the top example, onclick is associated with an express CALL TO the activateLasers function.  However, in the React example, onClick is simply associated with the activateLasers function (the syntax is not expressly calling the function, even though behind the scenes it does call it).  In this sense, in spite of its name React's onClick is more like this conventional JavaScript code:

```
.addEventListener("click", activateLasers)
```

Or is this the wrong way to think about it?

Comment: Note that there's HTML's `onclick` attribute and the DOM's `addEventListener` method and React's `onClick` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost, it looks like this:

```
// mapEventToComponent implemented by React
document.getElementById("root").addEventListener("click", mapEventToComponent,...);
```

In React, event handlers (like `onClick` handler) are [`SyntheticEvent` instances](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#generic-events).

It helps achieve high performance by using event delegation. React attaches a single event listener to `root` of the document (and not to nodes themselves), when an event called, React maps it to the component.

Check it yourself!

```
const Component = () => {
  return <button onClick={() => console.log("hello")}>Click</button>;
};
```

[image: Edit Synthetic Event]

1. Open dev tools
2. Fire the event to see if it's working.
3. Go to *Event Listeners* tab.
4. Check to which element all events attached.
5. Remove the `click` listeners from `#root` element.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think what I'm asking is more elementary. Which is whether it makes sense to regard React's onClick like the traditional onclick attribute one inserts in HTML.  They look nearly the same but are different.  The former attribute takes a value which is a reference to a function.  Whereas the latter attribute takes a value that's a call to a function.  This may seem obvious to an experienced React developer.  But the difference is a confusing adjustment to make for a newbie. IMO it might have been better for React to have called the attribute onClickFuncRef instead of onClick.

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you expect

Comment: Again, thanks for all your feedback.  My question is a cognitive one:  does it make any sense to regard the React onClick attribute like a standard html onclick attribute?  Based on the feedback, the answer appears to be that it's best not to regard it this way.  This is because the value associated with a React onClick attribute needs to be a REFERENCE to a function.  In contrast, the html onclick attribute needs to be a CALL to a function as in this example: https://jsbin.com/zoxeruy/edit?html,js,console,output .

Comment: Yes, need to be a reference