# Why is React calling an onClick function without being clicked on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, onclick

In the code below, there's an input form with a submit button. There's a map function which should display the items in `items` (which is a state array). I wanted to attach a button to every item displayed - that when clicked on, it should delete that item in the state array.

```
function App() {
  let [name, setName] = useState('')
  let [items, setItems] = useState([{id:1, name:"aaryan"}, {id:2, name:"dewan"}])

  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    //code to delete the element
    console.log("Hi World")
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <form>
    <label>
      Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" onChang  e={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
      <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
  </label>
  </form>
    {
      items.map((item) => {
        return(
          <div key={item.id}>
          <h2>{item.name}</h2>
          <button onClick={deleteItem(item.id)}>Delete</button>
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
  </div>
  )
}
```

**The problem**: When I type anything in the input box without clicking the delete button, `deleteItem()`gets called 4 times and displays 'Hi World'! Why is that happening? And how do I fix it?

**What I want** - `deleteItem()` should be called ONLY when I press the Delete button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<button onClick={deleteItem(item.id)}>Delete</button>
```

with

```
<button onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>Delete</button>
```

With the first approach you are directly calling the function on `render()`, so whenever the page renders you are calling the `deleteItem` function too.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make because React onClick seems like the onclick attribute one adds to an html element like in this example:  <button onclick="clickMe()">Click Me</button>.  But it's not the same.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66140454/is-react-onclick-more-like-a-javascript-addeventlistener-than-like-a-standard-ja