# React-Hooks: How to call a function returned by useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am a React newbie and would like to ask something probably pretty basic to you guys..!
So atm I'm learning how to use State Hook and here is some sample code I found on codeacademy course.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
 
function Toggle() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState();
 
  return (
    <div>
      <p>The toggle is {toggle}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setToggle("On")}>On</button>
      <button onClick={() => setToggle("Off")}>Off</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To my understanging, useState returns an array which consists of the current state and a function to update it. If you look at the button JSX element, it's calling that setToggle function when the button is clicked.

And this got me wondering,

**'Why is the setToggle function wrapped up with an arrow function? If setToggle is a function to change the current state, why can't we just call it without putting it inside of an arrow function?'**.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
 
function Toggle() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState();
 
  return (
    <div>
      <p>The toggle is {toggle}</p>
      <button onClick={setToggle("On")}>On</button>
      <button onClick={setToggle("Off")}>Off</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've run the code above but yes it didn't work:(
I looked up for some info but I don't know if this is too basic or something, I haven't been able to find an article that answers this question.

I really appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: Because it would execute instantly your component was mounted and not when the button was clicked.

Comment: To increase the relevance of your question I might rephrase it:  "Why does the syntax of React's onClick differ so much from the syntax of html's onclick?" Optimally I'd also add "And why was it designed that way?" That latter question btw has a empirical/historical answer that is useful to ppl who are interested in the historical context that inform language designer's design choices.  But unfortunately you wouldn't want to ask it on S.O. because it would (wrongly) be categorized as "opinion based."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an aspect of React that is hard to get used to because most of us are familiar with the onclick attribute in html which takes a call to a function like in this example:

onclick="myFunction(arg)"

But React's onClick doesnt work that way.  Instead think of it more like Javascript's addEventListener.  You assign it a function rather than a call to a function.  And if the function you want the event to execute is passing parameters then, as you note, it gets even more convoluted because then you have to wrap a function call in an anonymous function.  It doesn't make any sense if one comes from a context where one is accustomed to using html's onclick attribute.  But that's just how React's syntax works.

For some technical reasons why it works the way it does see:  [Is React onClick more like a JavaScript addEventListener than like a standard JavaScript onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66140454/is-react-onclick-more-like-a-javascript-addeventlistener-than-like-a-standard-ja)

Comment: Thank you so much, now it feels much more familiar when I think of it as something like addEventListener!

Answer (score 1):

The onClick function should be a event handler which handles SyntheticEvent in React.js.

```
onClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {}
```

If there are other cases which should handle the event, you should specify the parameter. e.g you gonna make the button disable.
But if there isn't, you can skip the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The[`onClick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) attribute requires a function that will be called when the `click` event occurs.

`onClick={setToggle("On")}`

In this case, the return value of `setToggle("On")` which is `undefined` is being set as the `onClick` event handler. This is effectively equivalent to not having an event handler at all, which means nothing will happen when the `click` event occurs.

`onClick={() => setToggle("On")}`

In this case, an anonymous function is created which when called, will also call the `useState`. Since `onClick` was provided with a function, it will execute it when the `click` event occurs, and in turn the `useState` is also called.

Comment: You forgot to put the arrow function in the arrow function example. :)