# click event order difference between onClick on addEventListener inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs

In the following React component, I attach a click listener to the root div in two ways:

- via `onClick` prop
- via a `useEffect` and `ref` and `addEventListener`

I also attach an `onClick` listener on the child div via prop.

When the user clicks the child, I assumed these events would fire in this order because of bubbling:

1. child onClick
2. parent onClick and click listener

However, the order is **actually**:

1. parent useEffect/addEventListener click handler
2. child onClick
3. parent onClick

There's clearly some detail about React, ref, or useEffect that's causing this but I'm not clear on what. Maybe the order in which the events are registered would be effected, but how would that matter when the actual click occurs?

```
export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const element = ref.current

      const handler = () => {
        console.log('addEventListener click handler')
      }

      element.addEventListener('click', handler)

      return () => {
        element.removeEventListener('click', handler)
      }
    }
  }, [ref])

  const onClick = () => {
    console.log('click triggered on parent')
  }

  const onChildClick = () => {
    console.log('click triggered on child')
  }

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
      <div onClick={onChildClick}>I'm a child, click me</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Reproduction: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bash-2xl9y3?file=/src/App.js:66-749)

When I build a similar structure in pure html/js, this doesn't happen.

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked child')
})

document.querySelector('._contextMenu_1tpfq_1').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked parent')
})

const parentOnClick = () => {
  console.log('parent onClick')
}

const childOnClick = () => {
  console.log('child onClick')
}
```

```html
<div class="_contextMenu_1tpfq_1" onClick="parentOnClick()"><ul class="_secondary_cxpiu_3"><li><a class="body-copy _anchor_2fp7v_1" onclick="childOnClick()">I'm a Child - Click Me</a></li></ul></div>
```

Reproduction: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/helion3/pen/LYXmQNd)

Comment: React has its own event system that works on top of native events in order to streamline and consolidate stuff like bubbling and this means it defers and batches handler invokation in a similar way to how state updates are pushed. A consequence of this is that any event handler that is added natively will be invoked first since it's outside of React's event system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React events are [`SyntheticEvent`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/events.html#generic-events) events, a wrapper around browser's native events for cross-browser support.

As indicated by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66140894/3930247), React achieves higher performance by attaching event listeners to **the `#root` element**. Reference can be found [here](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#react-event-object-caveats).

This means all your `onClick` handlers are actually event listeners attached to the `#root` element, which is the parent of them all.

You can check this by inspecting the element in Dev Tools, opening *Event Handlers* tab and checking *click* events (also indicated by the above answer). If you remove events attached to `#root` element, they no longer fire.

Due to bubbling, child events are triggered first, which means your `useEffect` event listener which is directly attached to the App component through native event handler fires first, because it's a child of `#root` in the DOM hierarchy.